Selecting values from java SIMD DoubleVector
I want to selectively insert values into a result array. Here's what I have so far.
  val sp = Matrix.doubleSpecies
  val l = sp.length()
  val vec : Array[Double] = ???
  val index : Array[Boolean] = ???
  while i < sp.loopBound(vec.length) do
    println(s"i: $i  || j: $j")
    val mask = VectorMask.fromArray[java.lang.Double](sp, index, i)

    val vals = DoubleVector
      .fromArray(sp, vec, i)

    // val selected = vals.selectFrom(vals, mask)

    println(s"mask: ${mask.toArray().print}")
    println(s"vals: ${vals.toArray().print}")
    vals.intoArray(newVec, j, mask)
    println(newVec.print)

    i += l
    j = j + mask.trueCount()

  end while

It fails my test. The troublesome diagnostic is here
  i: 4  || j: 3
  mask: [false,true],
  vals: [5.0,6.0],
  [1.0,3.0,4.0,*0.0*,6.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],

And Ive highlighted the 0.0 after the 4.0. What's happening, is that the intoArray function is inserting false values if they come before a true value. However, the false values after a true value are (per intent) ignored.
I found this surprising.
My question: what is the canonical way to insert a subset of double values from a DoubleVector into an Array[Double], without "gaps".
I found this;
val selected = vals.selectFrom(vals, mask) but it's throwing me an index out of bounds exception...

Left-packing is a hard problem for SIMD.  On x86, there's no hardware support for it until AVX-512 vcompresspd / ps, although you can hand-roll some stuff with BMI2 pext and bit-manipulation to generate an AVX2 shuffle control vector (AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?).  On AArch64, I think SVE has it, but most CPUs don't yet support SVE.  So I'm not really surprised that a generic SIMD API like Java's doesn't include a left-pack shuffle operation.

Hmmm... okay, that's very interesting to know - thanks for the response. It sounds like I should drop this particular algorithm for the time being :-).

If might be fairly easy to implement efficiently with 128-bit vectors of just 2 doubles, since there are only 2 possibilities (if you don't care about storing trailing garbage including in the no-valid-elements case), either both elements or the second element.  So you need one SIMD shuffle based on the first element being filtered out or not, and a popcount of valid elements to increment the write position.  You can index an array of shuffle-control vectors based on the first mask element being 0 or -1 (assuming it's a vector mask of all-0 or all-1 bits).

In fairness , part of the attraction here is the portability. If I understand correctly, this proposal makes assumptions about the vector shape - I would prefer to avoid that and allow the platform to pick its preferred shape. It’s not a big deal. Understanding the limitations is as important as the outcome for me
